# make Python3 script as a CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, command-line-interface

I have a single python3 script which has the following structure. I wish to make this code available as a CLI utility (and not a python3 module) via `pip`. The reason it not being a python3 module is because the logic is very straight forward and I see no benefit refactoring the code into smaller python files to make it a module.

#### Code `deflection.py`

```
def func1():
 """some useful function here"""


def main(args):
""" My MAIN Logic here!!"""


def parse_args():
"""Parse Arguments if Passed else use configuration file"""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='what the CLI should do.')


    parser.add_argument('--ip', type=str, required=False, help='descp@1')
    # Add more arguments (trimmed for code brevity)

    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    CONF = dict() # create a dict for reading a `conf.json` file from `/etc/` folder

    with open(CONF_PATH) as cFile:
        _conf = json.load(cFile)
        CONF = _conf['Key_Of_Interest']

   # Check Argument conditions
    if condition_1:
        print('Starting Script in Default Mode. Reading Conf File conf.json')
        try:
            main(...) # pass all the default args here

        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            # if CTRL C pressed safe exit
            sys.exit(0)

    elif condition_2:
        # if one particular argument wasn't mentioned, stop script
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print('Starting Script with Custom Arguments.')
        try:
            main(..) # custom args to main function
            
        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            # safe exit if CTRL C pressed
            sys.exit(0)
```

I am following the [Python-Packaging Tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which does mention `CLI` for python modules.

#### Current Directory Structure

```
.
|-- bin
|   `-- deflection
|-- deflection
|   |-- deflection.py
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- MANIFEST.in
|-- README.rst
`-- setup.py
```

#### `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup

def readme():
    with open('README.rst') as f:
        return f.read()

setup(name='deflection',
      version='0.1',
      description='Extract Micro-Epsilon OptoNCDT values and store into InfluxDB',
      long_description=readme(),
      url='https://mypersonalgitlabLink.com/awesomeCLIProject',
      author='Monty Python',
      author_email='Monty@python.org',
      license='GPLv3',
      packages=['deflection'],
      scripts=['bin/deflection']
      install_requires=[
            'influxdb-python'
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

At this point I am not sure what should be written in `bin/deflection` file?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from .deflection import main # NOT SURE Here! because main() requires arguments
```

I can decide simply upon `chmod +x deflection.py` but I have a dependency of `influxdb-python` which I wish to ship via `pip` i.e. when one does

```
`pip3 install deflection`
```

the users can directly do `$ deflection --arg1='test'` and use the script.

How do I achieve this without using `click` or any other helper modules and stick to core `pip`?

Comment: Please have a look at setuptools' "entry points": https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point

Comment: That makes sense, however if I directly call `main` from `deflection.py` the will it call `parse_args()` functions by default?

Comment: Just put the stuff in __name__ == '__main__' into the main function (or another one) and use this as entry point

Comment: That's what I did thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by @schlamar in the comment section:

I added all the code within the `__name__=='__main__'` block into a standalone function called `main()` and renamed the `main(args)` function to `send_data(args)`.

```
def send_data(args):
  """ refactor the function name"""

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    CONF = dict() # create a dict for reading a `conf.json` file from `/etc/` folder

    with open(CONF_PATH) as cFile:
        _conf = json.load(cFile)
        CONF = _conf['Key_Of_Interest']

   # Check Argument conditions
    if condition_1:
        print('Starting Script in Default Mode. Reading Conf File conf.json')
        try:
            send_data(...) # pass all the default args here

        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            # if CTRL C pressed safe exit
            sys.exit(0)

    elif condition_2:
        # if one particular argument wasn't mentioned, stop script
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print('Starting Script with Custom Arguments.')
        try:
            send_data(..) # custom args to main function

        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            # safe exit if CTRL C pressed
            sys.exit(0)
```

in my `bin/deflection` I added

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import deflection

if __name__ == '__main__':
   deflection.main()
```

Works all well now when I checked it in `virtualenv` using `pip install .` in the repo and `$ deflection` to check if it runs

Answer (score 0):

> At this point I am not sure what should be written in bin/deflection file?

Nothing. You shouldn't ship the executable inside the `bin` folder of your source tree. The executable will be created upon installation.

I suggest you to use [`flit`](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [`pyproject.toml`](https://snarky.ca/clarifying-pep-518/). It will greatly simplifies your project. First add a `pyproject.toml` file (instead of setup.py):

```
[build-system]
requires = ['flit']
build-backend = 'flit.buildapi'

[tool.flit.metadata]
module = 'deflection'
requires-python = '>=3'
description-file = 'README.rst'
requires = ['influxdb-python']

[tool.flit.scripts]
deflection = 'deflection.deflection:main'
```

Then upload your code to PyPI with `flit publish`.